# Is it a problem to store your vector database in memory?

Tags: vector-database, llm, chatgpt

I'm learning ChatGPT/LLM Development and am regularly coming across all different kinds of vector database implementations.

Some of them, e.g. [Chroma](https://docs.trychroma.com/), currently only support in-memory implementations for Python.

My initial reaction when I read that is "how can that be enough memory?". For what use cases are in-memory vector databases suitable?

Comment: Ikr, it is the same case with even `milvus`. I realised the trick is with indexing on how ANN based indices can be used.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean about this indexing trick?